# Linux boot2docker hosts not mounting home dirs

Tags: linux, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

If I create a Docker container on Linux using the VirtualBox driver for `docker-machine` and try to mount my local directory using the -v option to the `docker run` command the local directory does not mount.  For example,

`$ docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/code my_image`

where the current working directory is under `/home/myname`.

I tracked this down to the boot2docker VM in VirtualBox not mounting the shared folder called hosthome, defined in the VirtualBox configuration for the VM image.  (The auto-mounting of shared folders like `\Users` apparently works automagically when the VirtualBox host system is running Windows.)

If you log into the VM with ssh and run,

`$ sudo mount -t vboxsf hosthome /home`

then the home directory is mounted in the VM and subsequent `docker run` commands will bind-mount the local directory to the running container.

So I tried adding this mount command to the a bootlocal.sh script I created in the `/var/lib/boot2docker` directory on the VM.  But when I rebooted the boot2docker VM by using the `docker-machine stop` and `docker-machine start` commands the VM hung during boot up and I have no idea how to view its logs to know what went wrong.

How can I configure the VirtualBox boot2docker image to mount the hosthome share folder at boot time?

Comment: Just wondering, Why are you using boot2docker and VirtualBox on Linux?  IT would be a lot easier to just install docker straight to your OS if it's Linux.

Comment: How would I do that?  I'm running Ubuntu trusty.  When I install docker with apt-get that is the configuration I get.

Comment: This guide worked for me twice: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Thanks.  You referenced the Docker manual and I have spent time pouring over it.  It seems to indicate that docker machine is optional on Linux.  I guess I was following a tutorial for Mac thinking I was following a Linux tutorial.  Perhaps you can imagine how confusing it is to be told to remove docker machine when that is the only way you learned to launch containers.  I will try removing it.

Comment: I use docker-machine on Linux too.  So yeah, I would recommend also install docker-machine.  Yes, you have to install it separately but its worth it in my opinion.